Are there any examples of RAG using the stack exchange database?
Given the stack overflow/stack exchange database is open source and has built-in quality indicators (e.g., votes), it seems ripe for RAG applications. Can anyone point me to RAG projects that use the stack overflow data?

First of all, beware that Stack Exchange is trying to quietly change the data dump license and is planning to make it much more difficult to get the entire Stack Exchange dump: see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/401324/178179

Can anyone point me to RAG projects that use the stack overflow data?

Bing Copilot (example).
I believe Google Generative Search Experience also used the stack exchange database but it's turned off ATM on my side, so I can't confirm.

Otherwise it's simple (<10 min of human time) to import Stack Exchange data into Azure OpenAI:

which can later be called via e.g.:
import os
import pprint

from openai import AzureOpenAI
#from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential, get_bearer_token_provider

endpoint = os.getenv("ENDPOINT_URL", "https://[redacted].openai.azure.com/")
deployment = os.getenv("DEPLOYMENT_NAME", "[redacted GPT engine name]")
search_endpoint = os.getenv("SEARCH_ENDPOINT", "https://[redacted].search.windows.net")
search_key = os.getenv("SEARCH_KEY", "[redacted key]")
search_index = os.getenv("SEARCH_INDEX_NAME", "[redacted]")

# token_provider = get_bearer_token_provider(
#     DefaultAzureCredential(),
#     "https://cognitiveservices.azure.com/.default")

client = AzureOpenAI(
    azure_endpoint=endpoint,
    api_version="2024-05-01-preview",
    api_key='[redacted key]'
)
# azure_ad_token_provider=token_provider,

completion = client.chat.completions.create(
    model=deployment,
    messages=[
        {
            "role": "user",
            "content": "How can I sort a Python list?"
        }],
    max_tokens=800,
    temperature=0,
    top_p=1,
    frequency_penalty=0,
    presence_penalty=0,
    stop=None,
    stream=False,
    extra_body={
        "data_sources": [{
            "type": "azure_search",
            "parameters": {
                "endpoint": f"{search_endpoint}",
                "index_name": "[redacted]",
                "semantic_configuration": "default",
                "query_type": "vector_semantic_hybrid",
                "fields_mapping": {},
                "in_scope": True,
                "role_information": "You are an AI assistant that helps people find information.",
                "filter": None,
                "strictness": 5,
                "top_n_documents": 10,
                "authentication": {
                    "type": "api_key",
                    "key": f"{search_key}"
                },
                "embedding_dependency": {
                    "type": "deployment_name",
                    "deployment_name": "[redacted]"
                }
            }
        }]
    }
)
pprint.pprint(completion)

or, for client-side RAG using this basic RAG-QA codebase.
